# Can I run a Neo4j container with AWS Copilot for a website?

Tags: docker, neo4j, aws-copilot

I use Neo4j as the backend database for my web application.  I'm looking at AWS Copilot to manage the services, migrating away from Docker Compose.  For the last 5 years I've run Neo4j in a Docker container on an EC2 instance with the data persisted on an external EBS volume.

I'm finding the Copilot docs show how to set up a static website with no database, or (possibly) how to connect to one of their in-bred storage solutions like DynamoDB.  On the Neo4j side, all I see is how to set up the Neo4j AMI from the AWS Marketplace.

Could anyone explain or point me to an example of how to use AWS Copilot to deploy Neo4j in a Docker container and link it to a web service?  Or, if this is a bad idea, what would be a better approach?

Comment: Hey @HieroB, seems like you could run Neo4j on Copilot using your existing Dockerfile as long as you set up the EFS volume correctly. See my answer to your other question on EFS with Copilot at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72943854/5890422 for some more gory details on hydrating an EFS volume with a sidecar. If you set your `NEO4J_HOME` env var in the copilot manifest to point to your EFS volume, things should work fine with 1 copy of a task. This will be difficult to scale, however, and you run the risk of conflicted writes if you're writing to /data with multiple containers at once